# javascript, get the second class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Html code** :

```
<span class="button" onclick="javascript:buttonClicked();">Sign In</span>       
<div class="modal-bg" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal">
        <span>Sign In<a href="#close" class="close">&#215;</a></span>
        <form>
            <input id="username" name="username" type="textbox" placeholder="Username" required>
            <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
            <a id="forgot-link" href="#">Forgot password?</a>
            <button name="submit" id="submit" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

for the sign in button. For the sign up:

```
<span class="button" onclick="javascript:buttonClicked();">Sign Up</span>
<div class="modal-bg" style="display: none;">
<div class="modal">
<span>Sign Up<a href="#close" class="close">&#215;</a></span>
<form>
    <input id="FistName" name="FistName" type="textbox" placeholder="Fist Name" required>
    <input id="LastName" name="LastName" type="textbox" placeholder="Last Name" required>
    <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
    <input id="username" name="username" type="textbox" placeholder="Username" required>
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    <br><input style="margin: 0 -102px 0;" name="sex" type="radio" value="Male" checked="checked">Male
    <input style="margin: 0 -105px 0;" name="sex" type="radio" value="Female">Female<br>
     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Date of Birth<br>
    <select name="month" onChange="changeDate(this.options[selectedIndex].value);">
    <option value="na">Month</option>
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
    <option value="5">May</option>
    <option value="6">June</option>
    <option value="7">July</option>
    <option value="8">August</option>
    <option value="9">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
    </select>
    <select name="day" id="day">
    <option value="na">Day</option>
    </select>
    <select name="year" id="year">
    <option value="na">Year</option>
    </select>
    <input id="Adress" name="Adress" type="textbox" placeholder="Street address">
    <button name="submit" id="submit" type="submit">Sign up</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript code:

```
<script>
      $('.button').click(function(){
      $('.modal').css('display','block');
      $('.modal-bg').fadeIn();
});    
</script>

<script>
          $('.close').click(function(){
          $('.modal-bg').fadeOut();     
          $('.modal').fadeOut();
      return false;
    });    
</script>

<script>function buttonClicked()
{
$('.modal').show();
}
</script>
```

The sign in and sign up button when they are clicked a pop up window appears.The problem is that if you click either sign in or sign up button the sign up button appears.Because it is the second one and in my javascript i use classes that both of them have.How can i fix this? should i double the javascript code and use "something" that distinguish the second from the first class(for example the fist modal from the second modal) and how? ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `.next()`

```
$('.button').click(function(){
      $(this).next('.modal-bg').css('display','block');
      $(this).next('.modal-bg').find('.modal').fadeIn();
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/4rf2s3oa/4/)

or you can directly use

```
$('.button').click(function(){
      $(this).next('.modal-bg').fadeIn(2000);
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/4rf2s3oa/5/)

Comment: only there or everywhere in my javascript?

Comment: @A.JK use only this .. this code will open the next .model div of the button you will click on

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef - Using `.next()` solves the purpose but that also leads to strict html structure. I believe you should add a cautionary message for the same.

Comment: @A.JK I just see the piece of code you posted .. I don't have a full image of your website .. so if it works good in your website without modal{ display: none; } .. so no need to add it   .. but without display:none it will not give you the fade you want

Comment: @A.JK you can try this if you want  http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/4rf2s3oa/5/

Comment: Moreover! in my css i hava this
.modal:nth-child(1){
and this
.modal:nth-child(2){
why both enter in the first one ?

Comment: @A.JK what do you mean with (both enter in the first one)

Comment: i want diferrent height for each one. both have the height of .modal:nth-child(1){ but i whant the fist modal to have the height of .modal:nth-child(1){ and the second modal the height  of .modal:nth-child(2){

Comment: .modal:nth-child(1){
 top:25%;
 height:530px;
}
.modal:nth-child(2) {
 top:50%;
 height:260px;
}

Comment: @A.JK update my demo with your css code and lets see what we can do .. I think this is very simple thing .. but a demo will make me know what you trying to do

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MrLyffy/xw9ramb4/
i am sorry for my late response i did not have an account there..

Comment: @A.JK you need to center the divs vertically? .. 1st you have more and more of .modal:nth-child(1){  and .modal:nth-child(2){   (I know this is for responsive)  but 1st you need to remove margin-top:-130px; from .modal class and use top: 0 ; instead

Comment: removing margin top and add top because it is "bad" or "wrong" ? i mean by removing it my layout is not as i wanted. moreover center vertically? i do not know exactly what that means.

Comment: @A.JK by margin-top : minus it may put your div outside the screen so your user cant see the top of it anymore .. if top : 0; it will stick to top and start from top .. about centering the div vertically you should search for that .. and I should say you will need some efforts to make it center vertically .. and then you should modify nth-child(1) , (2)  in all of your media screen code and you will need overflow-y : auto for .modal-bg div .. to let scrollable and appear fine in small screens .. So you have more work to do

Comment: @A.JK and to be fair .. you can ask another question with your css and fiddle but in the css section (tagging css) and maybe you can find someone can help you in this ..